# Password Strength data-rule-pattern with jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, regex, passwords, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin and I want to create a password strength regex using `data-rule-pattern` to validate the field and can't make it work at all.

I want the password to have minimum:

- 8 characters
- 1 uppercase letter
- 1 number

So far I have:

```
<p class="controls">
<input data-rule-pattern="(^$)|([a-z][A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$)" data-msg-pattern="Password does not meet the minimum requirments." id="password" type="password" data-rule-required="true" value="" />
</p>
```

The other simple validations are working ok, but can't get this one done. Can anyone help please with some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)\w{8,}` something like this? I interpreted "characters" as `\w`.

Answer (score 2):

You can Apply your regular expression to the element with with customer addMethod 
like this

this is my custom addMethod that add regular expression

```
 $.validator.addMethod("PASSWORD", function (value, element) {
                    return this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,16}$/i.test(value);
                }, "Passwords are 8-16 characters with uppercase letters, lowercase letters and at least one number.");
```

this is my rules method that attach that custom addMethod to my element

```
 $('input[name="password"]').rules('add', {
                    PASSWORD: true
                });
```

this is my element

```
  <input id="password" type="password" class="w-input"  data-rule-required="true" name="password" placeholder="Password"  />
```

***OR***
You Can Directly Assign Your Custom Method To Your Element

```
<input id="password" type="password" class="w-input" data-rule-PASSWORD="true"  data-rule-required="true" name="password" placeholder="Password" data-rule-password ="true" />
Hope It Will work For You
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you think to include **additional-methods.js**?
Because pattern rule is not included in core **jquery.validate.js**!